# Installing Ant for Java on Linux

Tags: java, linux, cordova, ant

Trying to Install `ant` to package *Cordova* applications but I'm getting the following error upon executing the command `ant`:

> `/home/meronomy/java/jdk1.8.0_11/jre/bin/java: 1: /home/meronomy/java/jdk1.8.0_11/jre/bin/java: Syntax error: ")" unexpected`

Result of `java -version` is

`openjdk version "1.8.0_11" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-8u111-b14-2ubuntu0.16.04.2-b14) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14-2ubuntu0.16.04.2-b14`

Does anybody know could be wrong?

Comment: What is the result of `java -version`?

Comment: openjdk version "1.8.0_11" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-8u111-b14-2ubuntu0.16.04.2-b14) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14-2ubuntu0.16.04.2-b14

Comment: What command did you enter that resulted in this error?

Comment: Is JAVA_HOME set in your environment?  If so, what is it set to?

Comment: What is the output of the command `env|sort`? Please update the result in the question by using edit.